# Why does a motor not work after the power supply?

Tags: power-supply, motor

I have a fairly cheap breadboard power supply and a motor.

Now if I touch the wires from the adaptor (the thing that plugs into the power supply to provide it with electricity) the motor works fine and spins happily. I can adjust the voltage of this adapter to 3 volts - 12 volts, and the motor spins fine at all voltages. So I know the motor is working fine.

However if I plug the adaptor into the power supply and then try and power the motor from the power supply, it doesn't work. I try with both the 5 volt and 3 volt output of the supply. In fact the power supply appears to shut down - the led on it turns off.

What gives, why can this power supply not drive the motor? Is it just broken or is there some law of electricity I am not yet aware of (likely)?

*EDIT*

Ok, so this is the motor I have : [motor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4pcs-TT-Motor-130motor-with-the-wheel-2pcs-TT-motor-2pcs-65mm-wheel-Smart-Car-Robot/32898809340.html)

And the power supply I have is something similar this : [power](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B06WGQKJDL/)

I can't find many details about the motor. But I have noticed for the power supply it says :

> Maximum output current: <700 mA;

So I am guessing this is the problem? The motor likely needs more than that, especially if it needs 10x its requirement to get going.

Comment: If you have "a breadboard supply" and "a motor", all you can get is "an advice". To get any better answer, please provide details of your (a) motor; (b) "breadboard power supply" with schematics; and (c) details of your power adapter.

Comment: Most likely cause is the starting current of most motors is high - often 5-10x the rated current. Which will cause many power supplies to shut down before the motor's started. Does this apply to yours? No idea.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps it is quite telling I don't really know what I am doing, I am just using cheap bits I bought on AliExpress. I'll see if I can find any details.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Supposing this was the problem, is the solution to get a better power supply?

Comment: @MongusPong - Can you please edit your question and add photos of your hardware setup, including the motor and the things you are calling "adapter" and "power supply", as well as the wiring between them?

Comment: Solution is to understand what you are doing so you can choose a power supply that meets your needs.

Comment: Upvoting your question for confessing that "Perhaps it is quite telling I don't really know what I am doing", that's the proper attitude! LOL. There's probably lots of contact resistance somewhere, or a wire or something that was "cost optimized" in the cheap parts.

Comment: Your supply must be able to drive 10x the motor rated current and survive to work

Comment: It sounds like you have a voltage regulator module.  These **are not meant for powering motors**.  Further they are unnecessary for motors - motors use PWM *speed controls* not voltage regulators.